# Fluid width textarea with flexbox; percentage is ignored

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a text area centered on the page with a flexbox div which I would like to have 80% as wide as the page however with flexbox it seems that I can not use % as a unit for width.

My html:

```
<div class="textdiv">
    <form>
        <div>
            <textarea>
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
.textdiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

textarea {
  width: 80%;
}
```

When using flexbox the width is ignored unless I switch to another unit. Is there any way I can set the width of this text area to be 80% of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex on the div above the textarea:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <div class="textdiv">
            <textarea>
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
textarea {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
}
```

Change the position of textdiv class

Comment: That's fixed it. Thanks